# Dilemma while using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm using two tables for my current project(it will grow certainly).

First table has like loads of columns i.e.

```
id|name|surname|age|token         |currentpackage|difference
1 |me  | you   | 22|xc2e2144124sd |100           |0
```

Second table :

```
id|mirror|token|        connsize|price
81|server|xc2e2144124sd|100mbps |1000
```

These tables are full of data. There are some rows in the table1 that have same token value as the one in the table2.

I've googled for solution for quite alot, this is the best I found :

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/
and
http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html

But I don't think these apply to my case(or do they). In these examples the relation is key which is incremental, my token is just the way it is in the database.

My final goal is to be able to calculate the difference between currentpackage and price

What would you recommend for this? I'm using java/hibernate/spring

Is there any other way to tell hibernate to link by something else other that primary key?
some custom key like token in table 1? token is some kind relation between table one and table two. Its many(table1) to one(table2).

**LATEST UPDATE**

I'm trying to do it by using query to substract these two columns :

```
UPDATE packages tl 
SET difference = (select (t2.price-t1.currentpackage) 
from packages t1, mirrors t2 
where t2.token= t1.token)
```

I got this error :

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I must have tried many options but none worked

Tried this as well same result :

```
UPDATE packages X 
SET difference = (select Y.price-X.currentpackage
FROM packages X
LEFT OUTER JOIN mirrors Y
ON Y.token = X.token)
```

This seems to be what I'm looking for but I'm not able to incorporate it in my query :

[Subtract Values from Two Different Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254859/subtract-values-from-two-different-tables/5254939#5254939)

Comment: you mean there is no primary key in both/either table/s? to be able to use hibernate, primary key is must in all the involved tables.

Comment: @Bhushan of course there are primary keys in both tables, but they don't mean anything since they are different one from another, the only common column value is token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to map this relationship as many-to-one without making `token` an identifier in the second table. That said, there are several things you could do:

1. Do you even need to associate the tables? If your final goal is to calculate the difference between `currentpackage` and `price` as you said, seems like you could do that in a query.
2. If you do need to associate the tables, can you change your schema? I'm assuming `id` columns in both tables are primary keys. You can add `second_id` column (with whatever appropriate name) to the first table that will be a foreign key to second table and map them as many-to-one.
3. If you can't add a new column, can you make `token` a primary key in the second table? Is it unique / not null? This is a last resort, really, as it will involve generating `id` value in the database and / or mapping custom insert in Hibernate to preserve existing table structure.

**Edit (based on updated question):**

This now has little to do with Hibernate, since the query you're trying to execute is (a) update and (b) SQL-based, but nevertheless... Assuming I understood you correctly and you're trying to update 1st table to contain difference between appropriate row in the second table and current row in the first table, you can do the following:

```
update packages
   set difference = (select price
                      from mirrors m
                     where m.token = packages.token
   ) - currentpackage
```

Syntax may differ a little depending on your RDBMS; not all of them support correlated subqueries in update. Some support multiple table updates (like MySQL or Postgres), you can then write the query as:

```
update packages, mirrors
   set difference = mirrors.price - currentpackage
 where packages.token = mirrors.token
```

Comment: @ChssPly76 I guess I didn't work, I had query which didn't produce the correct output

Comment: @London If the relationship is truly many-to-one you'll need to use the aggregates (like `sum()`) in your query. You'll also need to correlate it with the table you're updating. There's no `difference` column in either of the tables you've shown, so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here.
.

Comment: @ChssPly76 sorry about that, I try to add as less columns as possible not to bother people with unnecesary complexity(not in this case though). I'll give it a go with sum and see what happens(although I need opposite of sum). thank you

Comment: @ChssPly76 darn it, not working, I've pasted errors here http://pastebin.com/dKKYxA8M , in the meantime I've tried to make couple of changes but none of them worked. thank you

Comment: @ChssPly76 stupid question, do I need many to one in my hibernate mapping file?

Comment: @London it's not working because (based on errors) you're trying to run this as HQL query. It's not HQL and it _cannot_ be HQL for HQL does not allow bulk updates with correlated subqueries. Define it as SQL instead; since it looks like you're using Postgres the proper query would be `update packages set difference = mirrors.price - currentpackage from mirrors where packages.token = mirrors.token`

Comment: @ChssPly76 Fantastic, you're a genious. yes finally some sleep. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky to make Hibernate to join tables by something other than primary key of one of the tables. You can some times get around this by doing a join the way Hibernate likes and putting your "logical join" condition into the were clause.

And if there's no join condition that Hibernate would like and suites your logic, you would have to do a Cartesian product.